# Исключение StringIndexOutOfBoundsException. Что необходимо исправить в коде?

Tags: java, исключения

Вылетает исключение StringIndexOutOfBoundsException. Jave учусь, и 12 часов не могу разобраться, как "обойти" это исключение.

Задание **Прочитать текст Java-программы и в каждом слове длиннее двух символов все строчные символы заменить прописными.**

**Мой код**

```
package OptionalTask.Task4;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class work {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try(FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("data/Task4.txt");
            FileReader reader = new FileReader("data/SomeJavaCode.txt");
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(writer);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader)){

            String line = null;
            String word = null;
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".{2,}");

            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                Scanner scan = new Scanner(line);
                while (scan.hasNext()) {
                    word = scan.next();
                    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(word);
                    if (matcher.matches()) {
                        buffer.append(matcher.group().toUpperCase() + " ");
                    } else {
                        buffer.append(word + " ");
                    }
                }
                bufferedWriter.write(buffer.toString(), 0, line.length());
                bufferedWriter.newLine();
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

При компиляции "выскакивает"

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 27
    at java.lang.String.getChars(String.java:821)
    at java.io.BufferedWriter.write(BufferedWriter.java:226)
    at OptionalTask.Task4.work.main(work.java:31)
```

Желательно разжевать все 4 строчки исключения.

Как понял их я:
**java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 27** - Вышел за длину в 27 символов (27 символов находится в первой строчке java кода, которое приложение считывает по пути "data/SomeJavaCode.txt")
**at OptionalTask.Task4.work.main(work.java:31)** - Ошибка находится в 31 строке кода. (bufferedWriter.write(buffer.toString(), 0, line.length());)

Ну и помимо исключений, хотелось бы получить ответ, как исправить свой код, что бы не болела голова.

В самой теме исключения, плаваю. Перекопав интернет, вычитал, что можно сделать доп. цикл, но прикрутить никуда не смог =)

Comment: *При компиляции "выскакивает"* - при выполнении.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка указывает на строку **31**.

На этой строке находится `bufferedWriter.write(buffer.toString(), 0, line.length());`

Могу предположить, что в *объект* **BufferedWriter** вы передаёте *объект* **StringBuffer** который хранит в себе строчки со всеми прописными буквами, А ТАК ЖЕ индексы от начала и конца строки. Индексация в программировании принято считать с **НУЛЯ**, а метод `line.length()` возвращает длину строки в **НАТУРАЛЬНЫХ** числах. Следовательно у вас *перемежается* понимание *человека* и понимание *компьютера*.

Получается, что `line.length()` возвращает вам длину строки, начиная с 1. Длина строки у вас 27 - **это логично**.

Но в памяти компьютера строка хранится как **массив символов**, а массивы индексируются **с нуля**. Следовательно последний **27ой** элемент *по* *человеческим* меркам будет иметь индекс **26**. То бишь вам нужно добавить `line.length() - 1`, чтобы удовлетворять условиям *индексации*.

По итогу должно получится как-то так :

`bufferedWriter.write(buffer.toString(), 0, line.length() - 1);`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.
`bufferedWriter.write(buffer.toString(), 0, line.length() - 1);` - от ошибки избавило. Вчера свой код я добавил, цикл for, ошибка тоже "ушла" и код выполняется, но "как то не так" ))

                   ` if (matcher.matches()){
                        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
                            buffer.append(matcher.group().toUpperCase() + " ");
                        }`

В общем решил одну проблему, вылезла другая))